# MDB Does Not Process Queue Message

Tags: java, jms, websphere, ibm-mq

I have a java application (jms) that can not get queue messages in IBM WebSphere MQ.

MQ Version: 9
WebSphere Application Server version: 9

- The messages are in queue, I can browse all  messages but the application still can not get messages but it get all new messages that arrive in the queue.
- We do not use selector in the messages
- In the queue exist messages persistent and not persistent. 
  The problem occurs with the two types of messages

IMPORTANT: when we move the messages to another queue (temporary) and move back to the main queue mdb can get messages normally.

Comment: What is the full WAS version.   What is the full IBM MQ version.   These will each have 4 numbers,  for example 9.0.0.5.

Comment: For clarification are you saying that your application can retrieve all messages that  arrive in the queue after the application starts, but can't seen any messages that arrived in the queue before the application started.

Comment: How do you read the queue (i.e. code!).  It obviously only reads messages on reception by MQ, and not all the messages in the queue.  Could be bad code or options on the reading function.